# Can an 19C asm instance be created after doing a software only install

Tags: oracle

I have installed ASM on 12c and 19c using the GUI.

In both methods it create a +DATA diskgroup.

Is it possible to do a simple Software only install and then manually create an empty ASM instance with file PFILE and ORAPWD  and then create and add disk (using oracleasm) later.

Comment: Basically when you have ASM you need install GI first and create ASM and afterwards you install the database

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Did a ASM only software intall from the grid.zip   but ASM said it needs Oracle Restart installed. It that a separate installed.